# How can I use `DateTime.now()` when I create an user in Flutter and Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a model user like this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final bool isAdmin;
  final bool canDeleteUser;
  final bool canCreateUser;
  final String nom;
  final String prenom;
  final DateTime createdDate;
  final DateTime modifiedDate;


  User({
    this.id = '',
    this.email = '',
    this.isAdmin = false,
    this.nom = '',
    this.prenom = '',
    this.canCreateUser = false,
    this.canDeleteUser = false,
    this.createdDate = DateTime.now(),
    this.modifiedDate = const DateTime.now(),
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UsersFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UsersToJson(this);
}
```

Fields createdDate and modifiedDate can't be initialize with DateTime.now(), I got this error message : The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

If someone can tell me how can I use Datetime.now() has a default value, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the parameters after the `{}` like so:

```dart
  User({
    this.id = '',
    this.email = '',
    this.isAdmin = false,
    this.nom = '',
    this.prenom = '',
    this.canCreateUser = false,
    this.canDeleteUser = false,
  })  : createdDate = DateTime.now(),
        modifiedDate = DateTime.now();
```

Full example:

```dart
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final bool isAdmin;
  final bool canDeleteUser;
  final bool canCreateUser;
  final String nom;
  final String prenom;
  final DateTime createdDate;
  final DateTime modifiedDate;

  User({
    this.id = '',
    this.email = '',
    this.isAdmin = false,
    this.nom = '',
    this.prenom = '',
    this.canCreateUser = false,
    this.canDeleteUser = false,
  })  : createdDate = DateTime.now(),
        modifiedDate = DateTime.now();
}
```